# Proper flow of Refresh JWT token implementation

Tags: node.js, server, jwt, frontend, backend

I am trying to understand the flow and implementation of refresh JWT.

1. When a user logs in, send a jwt token of the users info expiring in 15 min, and a jwt of some crypto letters expiring in 7 days.
2. Save the crytpo letters in the db.
3. On every request to the server, re-create the jwt token of the user and send it back.
4. On the clients end, when the jwt token of the users info expires, send a post request with the cryptic jwt token to a route which refreshes that token.

Is this flow correct? If so, when does the cryptic token get refreshed?

Comment: Check this out fot flow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0

Comment: @AymanArif Thanks! That's definitely helpful, but doesn't cover jwt so much. It's more about auth with google, twitter, etc.